# GridLayoutManager отступы разные

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

имеется `RecyclerView`, в котором применен `GridLayoutManager` при запуске программы в разных версиях `android` разные отступы как это можно исправить?

```
rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
rv.setLayoutManager(glm);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

вот пример на `android 4+`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример на `android 5+`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задать отступ явно. Если вы не задаете его, то берется значение поумолчанию из текущей темы, и оно, видимо, разное для разных версий

Comment: а как это сделать не подскажите?

Comment: погуглив меньше минуты, нашел ответ на ваш вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531996/android-recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-column-spacing